# How to connect to a database with 64 bit labview

Tags: sql, batch-file, 64-bit, executable, labview

So I am using labview and their data connectivity tool kit only works with their 32 bit version.  I need to use their 64 bit version though to be compatible with some of my other files.

If I have a local sql database, which I access using the mysql command line client, what would be the best way to talk to it?  Should I use executables like bat files or is there a better method?  Should I store data in a different way?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have never really liked the data connectivity toolkit, mainly because it is Windows only.  That being said, I recommend setting up a MySQL server on your computer and using TCP/IP to communicate with it.  This [community forum link](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-10453) is a good start, although there are some issues with this code.  I use code based off of that in my software, unfortunately I cannot post that source code.